# Visual Studio 2017 window list shows path but not filename

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 with the latest updates for both installed. A few weeks ago, the list of open files (Window | Windows...) stopped showing the filename. Now it just shows the path. I've included a screen snapshot showing an example.

[image]

This happens even for a newly-created project. How to resolve this?

Comment: The name of the file is `ConsoleApplication1`

Comment: In this case, that's the directory name. The name of the file is ConsoleApplication1.cpp, located in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what's going on. The Name column is actually there but is zero width. Somehow, the Path column got expanded to the very left of the window. I was able to click and drag on the left side of the Path column to reveal the Name column again.